# libGDX - gdx-backend-jglfw is missing and some others

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, libgdx

I am new to libGDX and trying to compile the source,

I have eclipse Luna 4.4.1
jdk1.8.0_11 installed, and JAVA_HOME is set
jre8
ant version 1.9.3 // executed ant -f fetch.xml in libGDX filder
clean all projects

but as I have touched nothing in the project there are 25 errors, 
it is my first JAVA-libGDX attempt and dying here...

```html
Description Resource Path Location Type
Project 'gdx-backend-jglfw' is missing required library: '/gdx/libs/gdx-natives.jar' gdx-backend-jglfw  Build path Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-jglfw' is missing required library: 'libs/gdx-backend-jglfw-natives.jar' gdx-backend-jglfw  Build path Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-jglfw' is missing required library: 'libs/jglfw.jar' gdx-backend-jglfw  Build path Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl' is missing required library: '/gdx/libs/gdx-natives.jar' gdx-backend-lwjgl  Build path Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-robovm' is missing required library: 'libs/robovm-cacerts-full.jar' gdx-backend-robovm  Build path Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-robovm' is missing required library: 'libs/robovm-cocoatouch.jar' gdx-backend-robovm  Build path Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-robovm' is missing required library: 'libs/robovm-objc.jar' gdx-backend-robovm  Build path Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-robovm' is missing required library: 'libs/robovm-rt.jar' gdx-backend-robovm  Build path Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-bullet' is missing required library: 'libs/gdx-bullet-natives.jar' gdx-bullet  Build path Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-controllers-desktop' is missing required library: 'libs/gdx-controllers-desktop-natives.jar' gdx-controllers-desktop  Build path Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-tests-lwjgl' is missing required library: '/gdx-box2d/libs/gdx-box2d-natives.jar' gdx-tests-lwjgl  Build path Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-tests-lwjgl' is missing required library: '/gdx-controllers-desktop/libs/gdx-controllers-desktop-natives.jar' gdx-tests-lwjgl  Build path Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-tests-lwjgl' is missing required library: '/gdx-freetype/libs/gdx-freetype-natives.jar' gdx-tests-lwjgl  Build path Build Path Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved gdx-backend-jglfw  Unknown Java Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved gdx-backend-lwjgl  Unknown Java Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved gdx-backend-robovm  Unknown Java Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved gdx-bullet  Unknown Java Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved gdx-controllers-desktop  Unknown Java Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved gdx-tests-lwjgl  Unknown Java Problem
The project cannot be built until its prerequisite gdx-tests is built. Cleaning and building all projects is recommended gdx-tests-android  Unknown Java Problem
The project cannot be built until its prerequisite gdx-tests is built. Cleaning and building all projects is recommended gdx-tests-gwt  Unknown Java Problem
The project was not built since it depends on gdx-backend-jglfw, which has build path errors gdx-tests-jglfw  Unknown Java Problem
The project was not built since it depends on gdx-backend-lwjgl, which has build path errors gdx-tools  Unknown Java Problem
The project was not built since it depends on gdx-backend-robovm, which has build path errors gdx-tests-iosrobovm  Unknown Java Problem
The project was not built since it depends on gdx-bullet, which has build path errors gdx-tests  Unknown Java Problem
```

in the error section of eclipse I am getting these maybe help to sort out the problem?

```html
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.8.0_11
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

org.eclipse.egit.ui
Warning
Mon Oct 27 20:15:01 EET 2014
Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\gokhan'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
*************************************************************
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.8.0_11
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

org.eclipse.egit.ui
Warning
Mon Oct 27 20:15:01 EET 2014
Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
*************************************************************
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.8.0_11
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

org.eclipse.ui.navigator
Warning
Mon Oct 27 20:14:59 EET 2014
Can't find Navigator Content Descriptor with id: org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui.EnhancedJavaRendering
```

I also check about the HOME folder, in system variable there exists JAVA_HOME to "C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.8.0_11"

so why do you think I am getting these error batch? thanks

Comment: If you're just trying to use libgdx you don't have to build the source. You just use it as a dependency for your project.

Answer (score 0):

Download nightlies zip from here. http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/

Make libs folder in each project and add the libraries which are missing from above zip.