# LIBGDX - Having a hard time loading libgdx/tests

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, ant, libgdx

I have been trying to load the test repository [libgdx/tests](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx) in eclipse for a couple of hours with no success at all.

I am using JRE 1.8 but compiler compliance level is 1.7. I have followed the tutorial here [How to running tests](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Running-Tests) to set up ANT (1.9.7) and GWT(2.6.1 [as recommended in the tutorial]).

I have cleaned all the projects and refreshed them. And i still get this huge bunch of errors because jars are not found (please, don´t tell me they have to be added by hand :? ):

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Project 'gdx-backend-jglfw' is missing required library: '/gdx/libs/gdx-natives.jar'    gdx-backend-jglfw       Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-jglfw' is missing required library: 'libs/gdx-backend-jglfw-natives.jar'   gdx-backend-jglfw       Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-jglfw' is missing required library: 'libs/jglfw.jar'   gdx-backend-jglfw       Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl' is missing required library: '/gdx/libs/gdx-natives.jar'    gdx-backend-lwjgl       Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl3' is missing required library: '/gdx/libs/gdx-natives.jar'   gdx-backend-lwjgl3      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl3' is missing required library: 'libs/lwjgl-glfw-natives-linux.jar'   gdx-backend-lwjgl3      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl3' is missing required library: 'libs/lwjgl-glfw-natives-macos.jar'   gdx-backend-lwjgl3      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl3' is missing required library: 'libs/lwjgl-glfw-natives-windows.jar' gdx-backend-lwjgl3      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl3' is missing required library: 'libs/lwjgl-glfw.jar' gdx-backend-lwjgl3      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl3' is missing required library: 'libs/lwjgl-jemalloc-natives-linux.jar'   gdx-backend-lwjgl3      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl3' is missing required library: 'libs/lwjgl-jemalloc-natives-macos.jar'   gdx-backend-lwjgl3      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl3' is missing required library: 'libs/lwjgl-jemalloc-natives-windows.jar' gdx-backend-lwjgl3      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl3' is missing required library: 'libs/lwjgl-jemalloc.jar' gdx-backend-lwjgl3      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl3' is missing required library: 'libs/lwjgl-natives-linux.jar'    gdx-backend-lwjgl3      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl3' is missing required library: 'libs/lwjgl-natives-macos.jar'    gdx-backend-lwjgl3      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl3' is missing required library: 'libs/lwjgl-natives-windows.jar'  gdx-backend-lwjgl3      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl3' is missing required library: 'libs/lwjgl-openal-natives-linux.jar' gdx-backend-lwjgl3      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl3' is missing required library: 'libs/lwjgl-openal-natives-macos.jar' gdx-backend-lwjgl3      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl3' is missing required library: 'libs/lwjgl-openal-natives-windows.jar'   gdx-backend-lwjgl3      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl3' is missing required library: 'libs/lwjgl-openal.jar'   gdx-backend-lwjgl3      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl3' is missing required library: 'libs/lwjgl-opengl.jar'   gdx-backend-lwjgl3      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl3' is missing required library: 'libs/lwjgl-stb-natives-linux.jar'    gdx-backend-lwjgl3      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl3' is missing required library: 'libs/lwjgl-stb-natives-macos.jar'    gdx-backend-lwjgl3      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl3' is missing required library: 'libs/lwjgl-stb-natives-windows.jar'  gdx-backend-lwjgl3      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl3' is missing required library: 'libs/lwjgl-stb.jar'  gdx-backend-lwjgl3      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl3' is missing required library: 'libs/lwjgl.jar'  gdx-backend-lwjgl3      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-robovm' is missing required library: 'libs/robovm-cacerts-full.jar'    gdx-backend-robovm      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-robovm' is missing required library: 'libs/robovm-cocoatouch.jar'  gdx-backend-robovm      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-robovm' is missing required library: 'libs/robovm-objc.jar'    gdx-backend-robovm      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-backend-robovm' is missing required library: 'libs/robovm-rt.jar'  gdx-backend-robovm      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-bullet' is missing required library: 'libs/gdx-bullet-natives.jar' gdx-bullet      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-controllers-desktop' is missing required library: 'libs/gdx-controllers-desktop-natives.jar'   gdx-controllers-desktop     Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-freetype' is missing required library: 'libs/gdx-freetype-natives.jar' gdx-freetype        Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-tests-android' is missing required source folder: 'gen'    gdx-tests-android       Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-tests-lwjgl' is missing required library: '/gdx-box2d/libs/gdx-box2d-natives.jar'  gdx-tests-lwjgl     Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-tests-lwjgl' is missing required library: '/gdx-controllers-desktop/libs/gdx-controllers-desktop-natives.jar'  gdx-tests-lwjgl     Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-tests-lwjgl' is missing required library: '/gdx-freetype/libs/gdx-freetype-natives.jar'    gdx-tests-lwjgl     Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-tests-lwjgl3' is missing required library: '/gdx-box2d/libs/gdx-box2d-natives.jar' gdx-tests-lwjgl3        Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-tests-lwjgl3' is missing required library: '/gdx-controllers-desktop/libs/gdx-controllers-desktop-natives.jar' gdx-tests-lwjgl3        Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx-tests-lwjgl3' is missing required library: '/gdx-freetype/libs/gdx-freetype-natives.jar'   gdx-tests-lwjgl3        Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx' is missing required library: 'libs/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar' gdx     Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'gdx' is missing required library: 'libs/junit-4.11.jar'    gdx     Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath container: 'GWT SDK [missing]' in project 'gdx-backends-gwt'  gdx-backends-gwt        Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath container: 'GWT SDK [missing]' in project 'gdx-box2d-gwt' gdx-box2d-gwt       Build path  Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath container: 'GWT SDK [missing]' in project 'gdx-controllers-gwt'   gdx-controllers-gwt     Build path  Build Path Problem
Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-1.7. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.     gdx-controllers-gwt     Build path  JRE System Library Problem
```

**NOTE**: I am aware of this question: [libGDX - gdx-backend-jglfw is missing and some others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594409/libgdx-gdx-backend-jglfw-is-missing-and-some-others) but it is rather old, so libraries have changed and there is no solution posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse complains about your JRE (bottom of your stack):

> Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-1.7. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.     gdx-controllers-gwt     Build path  JRE System Library Problem

you need [to set the property in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138384/warning-build-path-specifies-execution-environment-j2se-1-4) for preconfigured in the project JRE1.7

===============

The other build path problems should be resolved by running `ant -f fetch.xml` - make sure it succeeded.

Alternatively, you can run more specific ant task e.g. `ant -f fetch.xml fetch-lwjgl` to resolve dependencies, which should fix the

> Project 'gdx-backend-lwjgl3' is missing required library

===============

For missing GWT SDK problems:

- make sure you did:

  > GWT Plugin for Eclipse - follow the instructions on the page and install only required and GWT stuff
  >   Also make sure that default GWT SDK is 2.6.1. You will probably have to download it here and install it by going to Window/Eclipse -> Preferences -> Google -> Web Toolkit -> Add and then make sure it is checked.
- check it's actually there: e.g. right click on `gdx-backends-gwt` project `Build Path` - `Configure Build Path` - `Libraries` tab
  It should not have errors and correct path provided, like:

[image]

- do above for all three errored projects `gdx-backends-gwt`, `gdx-box2d-gwt`, `gdx-controllers-gwt`

Btw, 12/12/2016 devs changed it to gwt-2.8.0, see [commit a748656a](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/commit/a748656ada7b9502456cc95fa37cca5522439886), so maybe didn't update the instruction yet

===============

I also did `./gradlew build` - but it's not what causing your issues I think

Don't forget to clean-rebuild your eclipse:

> To resolve the issues do the following:
>
> Go to Project -> Clean Make sure all projects are selected, then click OK
>
> Select all projects in the package explorer, then hit F5 to refresh them (vodoo...)
>
> There will be a few issues remaining concerning GWT.
>   In the Problems view, right click on each entry saying "The web.xml
>   file does not exist", select Quick Fix and press OK

Even after that done I still have a problem :)

```
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplicationDelegateAdapter.
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. The ```ant -f fetch.xml```solved my problems, i didn't know how to use ant. I though the dependencies were managed by maven or gradle but they don't. Thanks again for taking your time to post such a detailed answer.